# Bluetooth is not working correctly

Tags: bluetooth

I am using a Dell Optiplex 9020 SFF. I installed a CSR 4.0 Bluetooth adapter for PC. It's working just fine under Windows 7. After installing Ubuntu 16.10, the Bluetooth device is connecting, and playing audio as usual from any device, but I can neither receive a file from any device nor send a file from my PC.

I've already run `rfkill list`, which shows no blockage at all, and the Bluetooth application is correctly installed. Now what should I do in order to send or receive files? There is no driver for Ubuntu in the adapter's installation CD.

Answer (score 0):

Search Dash for Personal file sharing, a icon looks like a folder. Open that. A small window should open with a checkbox (receive files over bluetooth). Check it. Close it. You can check the box beside Notify about received files too. Also, you can select which devices are to be shared with.